# Finding Zeros Of An Expression

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I write a program to plot this expression:

```
(a*z^2+c)+(a*z^2-c)*cos(2*u+m*pi)+b*z*sin(2*u+m*pi)=0
```

Where all of "a","b","c" and "z" parameters are known expressions and are just one variable expressions:"beta". And you is an expression of "lambda", so the main equation is an implicit expression of(lambda and beta).

Comment: There's no 'beta' in your equation but there *is* an 'm'. Are you sure you have the question correct?

Comment: I don't you try to study more, because this looks like homework.

Comment: m is 1 or 2. for example:
a=(tanh(w)/u)-tan(u)/w; w=sqrt(beta^2-n2^2);  u=sqrt(n1^2-beta^2)
 n1,n2=constant.
and so b,c and z are something like a.

Comment: b=((1/u^2)+(1/w^2))*tan(u)*tanh(w);
c=-(1/(u*w))*(tan(u)/u+tanh(w)/w);
z0=constant;  z=z0/u;
you see all of (u,w,a,b,c,z) are expressions of just one variable"beta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest some resources for you to study and learn by yourself

- [Using MATLAB To Evaluate And Plot Expressions](http://www.wepapers.com/Papers/5872/1_-_Using_MATLAB__to_evaluate_and_plot_expressions)
- [MATLAB Tips](http://www.nd.edu/~nancy/Math20550/Matlab/tips/matlab_tips.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try function [Solve](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html) (from Symbol Processing toolbox) and [ezplot](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html)

Comment: but when i'm using solve, because the net expanded equation is very complex, a warning: answers may be lost is displayed